# Is the returning function broken in Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby

I had a block of code that looked like this:

```
returning({}) do |hash|
attributes.each { |key, value|
        hash[key.underscore] = value
    }

end
```

Rewriting this to not use the returning magic fixed this method breaking with Ruby 1.9.3. Did this really fix something, or am I just missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: btw returning was deprecated and changed to `tap`

Comment: Using `returning`/`tap` is usually a bad idea. Here there is little doubt since you can simply write `Hash[attributes.map { |k, v| [k.underscore, v] }]`.

Comment: @tokland Why the hate on for [Kestrels](http://combinators.info/#kestrels)?

Comment: @dbenhur: yes, you can see `tap` as a K-combinator. However, SKI combinators are connected with lambda calculus and functional programming, so it's a somewhat painful to see it connected with a method that works by performing side-effects. Looking at raganwald's examples, he uses it to do side-effects like log or print, that's ok by me. But doing `[].tap { |x| x << 1 if condition ; x << 2 if condition2 }` as it's sometimes seen, well, that's terrible practice IMHO. In a nutshell: I prefer functional style and `tap` is imperative. Should be used only when there are real side-effects to do.

Comment: I mean, compare the original code with the functional (now using `Enumerable#mash` from Facets): `attributes.mash { |k, v| [k.underscore, v] }`. It's hard for me to see why you'd use `tap` for such a simple transformation.

Comment: I found a plugin to read OPML files. I upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3, and everything quit working.

I spent the evening debugging, found this function, found that it was very poorly documented, and I just wanted to understand what had changed such that this function would no longer return.

Thanks for the heads up on the Hash method to create the hash. I'll update my code, and be off and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `returning` was never a standard method in Ruby; it was supplied in Rails' ActiveSupport in earlier versions of Rails.  It is an implementation of the K-combinator commonly nicknamed [Kestrel](http://combinators.info/#kestrels).  The Ruby core library now supplies an equivalent method [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap). Just substitute the word `tap` for `returning` in your snippet and it will work as you expected.

However, for what you're trying to do, it is simply unnecessary. Use `map` and [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), for a much simpler expression:

```
Hash[ attributes.map { |k, v| [k.underscore, v] } ]
```

Comment: Since the question is about 1.9.3, this is the best way to do this without mutation. (The `#each_with_object` version in Sergio Tulentsev's answer is also idiomatic, but represents a different style.) As of Ruby 2.1, though, there's an improved way to do this: `attributes.map { |k, v| [k.underscore, v] }.to_h`

Comment: @Peeja a fine suggestion, but beware of adopting the newest idiom too quickly, especially in library code which you may want to reuse in programs targeting older Rubies.

Answer (score 1):

I personally never heard of `returning`. But your snippet can be rewritten with more standard methods.

```
attributes.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), memo|
  memo[key.underscore] = value
end
```

Comment: Or simply `Hash[attributes.map { |k, v| [k.underscore, v] }]`.

Comment: `returning` was an implementation of the K combinator in very old versions of Rails a very long time ago. It has never been a part of Ruby and has been deprecated in Rails for ages. Current versions of Ruby provide the K combinator in the form of `Object#tap`.